# Почему шлюз блокирует Центр обновления Windows?

Tags: windows, администрирование, сеть, windows-server

Раздаю интернет с хоста виртуальным машинам через локальную сеть. Но они не могут скачать обновления, хотя хост их качает. Как разблокировать доступ к центру обновлний для виртуалок?

Comment: Информации для ответа недостаточно. Нужно знать какие средства защиты установлены на хосте. Какой firewall, какие на нем установлены правила и т.д.

Comment: И что за виртуализация используется?

Comment: Роль Hyper-V в Windows Server 2012 r2 Datacenter. Windows Firewall с правилами по умолчанию (после установки запустил Enable-NetFirewallRule). Антивирусов не ставил никаких. Еще включен Smart Screen.

Comment: в C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log на виртуалках загляните